# Is there a recent CPTableView tutorial using IB?

Tags: xcode, cappuccino, objective-j

I'm looking for a recent Cappuccino tutorial that shows how to implement a CPTableView using IB/Xcode 4 with XcodeCapp -- all of the CPTableView examples that I've found are fully implemented in code vs XIB/CIB.

Comment: I found a GREAT tutorial of using CPTableView in a CIB along with a CPArrayController at the following URL: http://www.headz.be/wordpress/?p=214

Comment: ^ This should be an answer, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [very recent tutorial showing CPTableView, Xcode, bindings and more](http://coltrane.music.mcgill.ca/tutorials/capptutorial1/).